# Error 1004 vba pivot filter contains value

Tags: vba, filter, runtime-error, pivot-table

this code is running well at initially. 
But Error 1004 come out after few times testing.
the code break at this line

```
Set Field = pt.PivotFields("Rep Order#")
```

I have checked the field name in pivot table. it is exactly the same.

Can anyone help to have a look ?

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    'Set the Variables to be used
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim pt2 As PivotTable
    Dim Field As PivotField
    Dim Field2 As PivotField
    Dim pivot_item As PivotItem
    Dim pivot_item2 As PivotItem
    Dim NewCat As String
    Dim test_val As String

    'Here you amend to suit your data
    Set pt = Worksheets("Backlog Analysis 2").PivotTables("PivotTable2")
    Set pt2 = Worksheets("Backlog Analysis 2").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
    Set Field = pt.PivotFields("Rep Order#")
    Set Field2 = pt2.PivotFields("Rep Order#")

    NewCat = Worksheets("Backlog Analysis 2").Range("L11").Value

    'Here is the test if the input field exists
    test_val = NewCat
    For Each pivot_item In pt.PivotFields("Rep Order#").PivotItems
        If pivot_item.Name = test_val Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next pivot_item
    On Error Resume Next

    'This updates and refreshes the PIVOT table
    With pt
        Field.ClearAllFilters
        Field.PivotFilters.Add2 Type:=xlCaptionContains, Value1:=NewCat
        pt.RefreshTable
    End With

    With pt2
        Field2.ClearAllFilters
        Field2.PivotFilters.Add2 Type:=xlCaptionContains, Value1:=NewCat
        pt.RefreshTable
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the code works initially and then stops working, my first guess would be to either turn off Events or limit the code to run only when a specific range changes. Your code now we run every time anything changes in the workbook (including when your code changes the Pivot Tables).

Try adding this at the beginning of your code:

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

And this at the end:

```
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Alternatively, it appears that you really only want this to run when Range("L11") changes. So, you could add a conditional at the top:

```
If Target.Address = "$L$11" And Sh.Name = "Backlog Analysis 2" Then
    'Run Your Code
End If
```